# Pagination repeating posts on search results

Tags: wp-query, functions, pagination, search

i have a problem with my wordpress search result pagination. Basically it's working as intended until i hit page 2, it then repeats the results of page one. Here is my search.php, please excuse the messy formatting.. i'm a beginner and have been hacking at it for days. Cheers in advance!

```
<?php get_header(); ?>


<div class="inner">
<div class="Search-results"
<?php  _e("<h3>Search Results for: ".get_query_var('s')."</h3>"); ?>
</div>

<!-- Boxes -->
<div class="thumbnails">
        
<?php
$s=get_search_query();
$args = array('s' =>$s);
    // The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
       
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
$the_query->the_post();
?>
<div class="box">
 
<div class="image fit"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array( 250,225 ), array( 'class' => 'alignleft' )); ?> </div>
 
<div class="post-details"><?php the_time('d/m/Y'); ?></div>
<div class="post-details2"><?php if(function_exists('the_views')) { the_views(); } ?></div>
 
<div class="inner">
<a href="<?php the_permalink()?>"><h3><?php the_title();?></h3></a>
<p><?php the_content(''); ?></p>
</div>

             
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="button fit">Check it out!</a>
</div>

<?php
        }
    }else{
?>
        
<p>Sorry, but nothing matched your search criteria. Please try again with some different keywords.</p>
  
<?php } ?>

<?php wpbeginner_numeric_posts_nav(); ?> 

    
                       </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

 

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Here is my search form

```
<!-- SEARCH -->
<div class="select-wrapper-top">            
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" role="search">
<input type="text" class="field" name="s" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_search_query() ); ?>" id="s" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search &hellip;', 'shape' ); ?>" />
<button type="submit" class="btn">
<i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-lg"></i> 
</button>
</form>
</div>
<!-- END SEARCH -->
```

...and here are my page numbers if applicable in functions.php

```
   /** START PAGE NUMBERS */

function wpbeginner_numeric_posts_nav() {
 
    if( is_singular() )
        return;
 
    global $wp_query;
 
    /** Stop execution if there's only 1 page */
    if( $wp_query->max_num_pages <= 1 )
        return;
 
    $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
    $max   = intval( $wp_query->max_num_pages );
 
    /** Add current page to the array */
    if ( $paged >= 1 )
        $links[] = $paged;
 
    /** Add the pages around the current page to the array */
    if ( $paged >= 3 ) {
        $links[] = $paged - 1;
        $links[] = $paged - 2;
    }
 
    if ( ( $paged + 2 ) <= $max ) {
        $links[] = $paged + 2;
        $links[] = $paged + 1;
    }
 
    echo '<div class="navigation"><ul>' . "\n";
 
    /** Previous Post Link */
    if ( get_previous_posts_link() )
        printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_previous_posts_link('Previous') );
 
    /** Link to first page, plus ellipses if necessary */
    if ( ! in_array( 1, $links ) ) {
        $class = 1 == $paged ? ' class="active"' : '';
 
        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ), '1' );
 
        if ( ! in_array( 2, $links ) )
            echo '<li>-</li>';
    }
 
    /** Link to current page, plus 2 pages in either direction if necessary */
    sort( $links );
    foreach ( (array) $links as $link ) {
        $class = $paged == $link ? ' class="active"' : '';
        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $link ) ), $link );
    }
 
    /** Link to last page, plus ellipses if necessary */
    if ( ! in_array( $max, $links ) ) {
        if ( ! in_array( $max - 1, $links ) )
            echo '<li>-</li>' . "\n";
 
        $class = $paged == $max ? ' class="active"' : '';
        printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $max ) ), $max );
    }
 
    /** Next Post Link */
    if ( get_next_posts_link() )
        printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_next_posts_link('Next') );
 
    echo '</ul></div>' . "\n";
 
}
```

Comment: If you use `search.php` then your custom `WP_Query` is unnecessary and a standard post loop would work, and pagination would fix itself. That custom query does nothing but cause you problems. If you ever want to change the main query, maybe to add/remove/replace a parameter, use the `pre_get_posts` hook, don't use `WP_Query`

Comment: My goodness.. so simple!! Thanks a lot! I guess i was just over doing it.. didn't know you could just use a standard loop! Cheers!!